# vector<int> v(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());

Tags: c++, declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>()); //Compilation error?!
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Why that line goes error? 
I know the compiler thouht 'v' as a function! Amazing...

Comment: It would be nice if you could tell us what the actual error is that you're getting...

Answer (score 6):

This problem is known as C++'s [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Try changing the first line to the following (note the extra parentheses):

```
vector<int> v((istream_iterator<int>(cin)), istream_iterator<int>());
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified by @Kyle Lutz, it's the most vexing parse problem, that is also often solved by changing the initialization to something like:

```
vector<int> v=vector<int> (istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
```

which tends to be better understood than the "double parenthesis trick".

Answer (score 0):

When I try to compile it, the only errors I get are on the *next* line, where it complains that `v.begin()` and `v.end()` aren't valid because `v` isn't a class/struct/union (for the obvious reason that, as already noted, you've encountered the most vexing parse).

Answer (score 0):

If you would just add one extra line, your could avoid the MVP, and your code would, imo, be much more readable, and less repetetive.

```
istream_iterator<int> b(cin), e;
vector<int> v(b,e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here there are function pointer declarations used as a function parameter:

```
int f(int (*funa)());
int f(int funa());
int f(int());//The parameter name can be omitted, such as the function declaration int g(double p); is equal to int g(double);
```

So, look at your problem:

```
vector<int> v(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
```

Yes, yes, we know `istream_iterator<int>(cin)` is a `istream_iterator<int>` type parameter. **However, the second parameter is the problem we encounter: `istream_iterator<int>()` can be understood as a pointer to a function which returns `istream_iterator<int>` and has no parameters. This makes compiler confused, `v` may be a function declaration or a verb definition. If the second parameter is not a function pointer, `v` is a verb definition.**

We can fix your problem by two ways, first you can declare the iterators and then use them in `v`:

```
istream_iterator<int> dataBegin(cin);
istream_iterator<int> dataEnd;
vector<int> v(dataBegin, dataEnd);
```

The second way to fix it is :

```
vector<int> v((istream_iterator<int>(cin)), istream_iterator<int>());
```

we add `()` around the first element which tells the compiler it is a verb, not a parameter, so the second element must be a verb too. That's all.